# Unable to Deserialize Attributes

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization, attributes

I have the following element in some XML which I need to deserialize:

```
<settlementLineItem number="1">
    <amountPaid>38250.89</amountPaid>
    <originalAmount>42501.00</originalAmount>
    <adjustmentAndDiscount>
        <amount>850.02</amount>
        <adjustmentReason>
            <messageReason>XG 2.000 % Distribution Allow.</messageReason>
            <sourceCode>TNT</sourceCode>
        </adjustmentReason>
        <alternateAdjustmentReference>
            <alternateAdjustmentReferenceType>DOC_NO</alternateAdjustmentReferenceType>
            <identification>2200527269</identification>
        </alternateAdjustmentReference>
    </adjustmentAndDiscount>
    <adjustmentAndDiscount>
        <amount>2125.05</amount>
        <adjustmentReason>
            <messageReason>XI 5.000 % Incentive Discount</messageReason>
            <sourceCode>TNT</sourceCode>
        </adjustmentReason>
        <alternateAdjustmentReference>
            <alternateAdjustmentReferenceType>DOC_NO</alternateAdjustmentReferenceType>
            <identification>2200528098</identification>
        </alternateAdjustmentReference>
    </adjustmentAndDiscount>
    <adjustmentAndDiscount>
        <amount>1062.53</amount>
        <adjustmentReason>
            <messageReason>XF 2.500 % Advertising Allow.</messageReason>
            <sourceCode>TNT</sourceCode>
        </adjustmentReason>
        <alternateAdjustmentReference>
            <alternateAdjustmentReferenceType>DOC_NO</alternateAdjustmentReferenceType>
            <identification>2200529157</identification>
        </alternateAdjustmentReference>
    </adjustmentAndDiscount>
    <adjustmentAndDiscount>
        <amount>212.51</amount>
        <adjustmentReason>
            <messageReason>XO 0.500 % Training &amp; Dev. Cost</messageReason>
            <sourceCode>TNT</sourceCode>
        </adjustmentReason>
        <alternateAdjustmentReference>
            <alternateAdjustmentReferenceType>DOC_NO</alternateAdjustmentReferenceType>
            <identification>2200529467</identification>
        </alternateAdjustmentReference>
    </adjustmentAndDiscount>
    <invoice creationDateTime="2017-06-28">
        <uniqueCreatorIdentification>4912115908</uniqueCreatorIdentification>
        <contentOwner>
            <gln>6001000000001</gln>
        </contentOwner>
        <invoiceType>CREDIT_NOTE </invoiceType>
    </invoice>
    <settlementEntity entityType="SITE">
        <partyIdentification>
            <gln>6001007031336</gln>
        </partyIdentification>
    </settlementEntity>
</settlementLineItem>
```

I am using this class to represent that particular element:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "settlementLineItem")]
public class SettlementLineItem
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    // Standard data
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "amountPaid")]
    public string AmountPaid { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "originalAmount")]
    public string OriginalAmount { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoice")]
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "settlementEntity")]
    public SettlementEntity SettlementEntity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "adjustmentAndDiscount")]
    public List<AdjustmentAndDiscount> AdjustmentAndDiscount { get; set; }

    // Exetension data
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "documentType")]
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "documentNumber")]
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "itemText")]
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
}
```

The code which performs the deserialization:

```
private Message DeserializeXml(string xml)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        return (Message)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

All the elements apper to deserialize without any problems, but the `Number` attribute is always `null`.

I am seeing this issue for all attributes in the document which I am trying to deserialize.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Note that I have not included the entire xml message (it is huge, and of type `Message`), but this should be enough information, as the deserialization itself is successful (just not when it comes to attributes).

Thanks!

---

**Edit**

Code for `Invoice`, `SettlementEntity`, `AdjustmentAndDiscount`

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "invoice")]
public class Invoice
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "uniqueCreatorIdentification")]
    public string UniqueCreatorIdentification { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "contentOwner")]
    public ContentOwner ContentOwner { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoiceType")]
    public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "settlementEntity")]
public class SettlementEntity
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "partyIdentification")]
    public PartyIdentification PartyIdentification { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "adjustmentAndDiscount")]
public class AdjustmentAndDiscount
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "adjustmentReason")]
    public AdjustmentReason AdjustmentReason { get; set; }

    // LineItem data
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "alternateAdjustmentReference")]
    public AlternateAdjustmentReference AlternateAdjustmentReference { get; set; }

    // Summary data
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "amountTotal")]
    public string AmountTotal { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "amountNet")]
    public string AmountNet { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "amountVAT")]
    public string AmountVAT { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the class Invoice , SettlementEntity , AdjustmentAndDiscount ?

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ I added the code, but not sure if it will help. This attribute deserialization issue is happening at all levels of the document

Comment: I did the same it's working for me . check my code

Answer (score 1):

I have created an xml file inside the application named as "XMLFile1.xml" and copied your xml string to the "XMLFile1.xml" file.

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DeserializeXMLConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\My Apps\Console Applications\DeserializeXMLConsoleApp\DeserializeXMLConsoleApp\XMLFile1.xml");
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SettlementLineItem));
            using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                var finalResult =  (SettlementLineItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "adjustmentReason")]
    public class AdjustmentReason
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "messageReason")]
        public string MessageReason { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sourceCode")]
        public string SourceCode { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "alternateAdjustmentReference")]
    public class AlternateAdjustmentReference
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "alternateAdjustmentReferenceType")]
        public string AlternateAdjustmentReferenceType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "identification")]
        public string Identification { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "adjustmentAndDiscount")]
    public class AdjustmentAndDiscount
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "amount")]
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "adjustmentReason")]
        public AdjustmentReason AdjustmentReason { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "alternateAdjustmentReference")]
        public AlternateAdjustmentReference AlternateAdjustmentReference { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "contentOwner")]
    public class ContentOwner
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "gln")]
        public string Gln { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "invoice")]
    public class Invoice
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "uniqueCreatorIdentification")]
        public string UniqueCreatorIdentification { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "contentOwner")]
        public ContentOwner ContentOwner { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoiceType")]
        public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "creationDateTime")]
        public string CreationDateTime { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "partyIdentification")]
    public class PartyIdentification
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "gln")]
        public string Gln { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "settlementEntity")]
    public class SettlementEntity
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "partyIdentification")]
        public PartyIdentification PartyIdentification { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "entityType")]
        public string EntityType { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "settlementLineItem")]
    public class SettlementLineItem
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "amountPaid")]
        public string AmountPaid { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "originalAmount")]
        public string OriginalAmount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "adjustmentAndDiscount")]
        public List<AdjustmentAndDiscount> AdjustmentAndDiscount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoice")]
        public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "settlementEntity")]
        public SettlementEntity SettlementEntity { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT** > See the Number attribute value

[image]

Please check and revert me back if it solves your problem or not.

Comment: I added the attribute declerations to the hcild classes as in your code, but sitll seeing the same issue. I didn't mention that the data is coming in via a WCF service, maybe that is affecting it?

Comment: Oh!. Then that could be separate scenario. As per your provided xml string , it's working as expected. Find the exact error/problem in your application and create another question..mentioning the exact problem for that...if required :)